# How to write regex pattern in lucene?

Tags: java, regex, lucene

I want to match a string from regexp query in lucene.

Test String:

```
       program-id.  acinstal.
```

Regex pattern in java:

```
^[a-z0-9 ]{6}[^*]\s*(program-id)\.
```

How would i write this regex specifically for lucene regexp query to match the string.

Comment: `PROGRAM-ID|program-id` you'd probably want to use a case-insensitive query. Not sure how you'd do it in lucene but Java has the `(?i)` option for that.

Comment: @Thomas: thanks for answering, but i need lucene's specific regex query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two problems with your regex (assuming here, based on previous questions, that your test string is indexed without any tokenization.  As a `StringField`, for instance):

1. The regex must match a whole term.  Without any analysis, as we're assuming, that means it must match *the whole field*.  In this case, you need to add a `.*` to match the rest of the field
2. Since you have to match the whole field anyway, anchors are not supported, so get rid of the `^` at the beginning.

So the regex that should work is:

```
[a-z0-9 ]{6}[^*]\s*(program-id)\..*
```

Comment: Is there any way to run multiple regex in lucene by grouping them with AND OR operators.

Comment: @rocky - Yes, you can combine multiple queries with [BooleanQuery](https://lucene.apache.org/core/5_4_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/BooleanQuery.Builder.html).

Comment: [A-Z0-9 ]{6}[^*]\s*environment\s+division\..*
its not working, can you please tell me what's wrong with this pattern??

Comment: The `\s` escape sequence is not supported.  [See the docs](https://lucene.apache.org/core/5_4_0/core/org/apache/lucene/util/automaton/RegExp.html) for what regex syntax is available in lucene.