# How to write an IP address regex query for Lucene 8.2?

Tags: java, regex, lucene

I am using a standard analyzer, and the RegexpQuery class,
when I display query.toString() I get

**content:/(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9]?[0-9])\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9]?[0-9])/**

with **content** being the name of my field.

This doesn't match with a document containing the line **IP address: 123.45.67.89**

What is wrong with my regex? Or am I doing something else wrong?

Edit: If I change the query to **content:/123.45.67.89/** it matches.

Edit2: Am I escaping the '.' incorrectly? The regex is trying to match a literal '.', and not the wildcard any character form of '.'

Comment: Perhaps this page might be helpful. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35552956/how-to-write-regex-pattern-in-lucene

Comment: Use `content:/(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9]?[0-9])(\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9]?[0-9])){3}/`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks for your response. I see two changes in mine versus yours. 1. I have 'non-capturing groups' notation '(?:' and you have 'capturing groups' notation '('. 2. I have the 'dot' and need 3 occurrences on the first group, and you moved them as part of the second group. Are 'non-capturing groups' not allowed in Lucene Regex? Is there a reason you re-arranged the 'dot' and the '{3}'? In my mind the 2nd change isn't necessary, but maybe it is more efficient?

Comment: Did it work for you? There is always a reason for me to change  a pattern, just let me know if I can post it as an answer.

Comment: Please tell me why you changed the pattern. I tested both yours and mine without the '?:' and both worked. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: What do you mean? If your regex works, what is the point of the question?

Comment: Mine didn't work until I changed '(?:' to '('

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to convert non-capturing groups to capturing ones because [Lucene regex engine](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/regexp-syntax.html) does not support the former:

```
content:/(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9]?[0-9])(\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9]?[0-9])){3}/
```

Note I replaced the `(<part>){3}(part)` to `(part)(<part>){3}` syntax because this is best practice in regex, to place quantified subpatterns as close to the right as possible, it reduces backtracking.